# How to create a pop up window when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, popupwindow

This is the code I have for the  button. I want the configbutton to display a pop up window when clicked on. I have looked up and tried a lot of different codes but none of them work. I feel like I am missing a key component but I am not sure what that is. Appreciate the help!

```
tr = new TableRow();
// Create the cell
tc = new TableCell();
tc.Width = Unit.Point(300);
tc.BorderWidth = 0;
tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

Button ConfigButton = new Button();
ConfigButton.Text = "Configuration";
ConfigButton.Visible = true;

tc.Controls.Add(ConfigButton);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
```

Comment: if you just want to show a string message a `MessageBox` should be enough, add a handler for the button's `Click` event and show the `MessageBox`

Comment: What is in the popup window?

Comment: The previous comment say use `MessageBox` and your question say __popupwindow__.  When I think is __popupwindow__ I am thinking you are doing ASP.Net and you want a **javascript** solution.  MessageBox sounds more like WinForm and dialog box.

Comment: Is this for a website?  It looks like WebForms code.

Comment: [`TableRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.aspx) looks like [tag:asp.net] to me.

Comment: its asp.net, and its for a part of a website. the config button should show a popup box with field names. however I cant seem to get that to work

Comment: @Gunther34567 this is a webforms question, MessageBox solution is for winforms and will not work here.

Comment: @taybriz yeah i posted the comment before the asp tag was added

Answer (score 0):

[Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) you will do the following:

```
// when you create the button, you can add attributes
Button ConfigButton = new Button();

// this example will display alert dialog box
ConfigButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('ALERT ALERT!!!')");

// to get you popup windows
// you would use window.open with the BLANK target

ConfigButton.Text = "Configuration";
ConfigButton.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into using the AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender. This is what I use for my pop ups in ASP.NET.

Here is a link to he AJAX Control Toolkit samples website showing how this control works:
http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx